# Mathematical calculation in label - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not even sure if this is possible however I'm been looking around online for a while now and have not seen any syntax that provides the solution. I'd like to include a mathematical calculation in my select statement label. So for the below example, I'd like to label the select statement with a calculation within the label:

```
SELECT a.data1         AS "Data X" 
      ,a.data2/a.data3 AS "Data Y(" || a.data4/a.data5 || " Avg)"
  FROM alpha a
```

Output should be something like this:

```
+--------+----------------+
| Data X | Data Y(25 AVG) |
+--------+----------------+
| 100    | 50             |
+--------+----------------+
```

Sorry for the over simplifications just wanted to clarify exactly what I'm trying to do. Any ideas would be much appreciated if this is even possible. If it's not just letting me know it isn't would also be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: i don't think you can use calculations or concatenation in column-aliases. you have to specify them literally.

Comment: Not in pure SQL. You can do it in plpgsql in EXECUTE statement

Comment: OK great thanks you for clarifying that, it's much appreciated.